# How can I filter the imagefield by filename in django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I add a ImageField in my model like

```
class UserImage(models.Model):
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='target_path')
    ....
```

after I save an image, let's say 'a.jpg', then I want user the filename 'a.jpg' to filter the model, what should I write like:

```
UserImage.objects.filter(photo.filename='a.jpg')
....
```

Answer (score 20):

Your suggestion would give you an error. Try this instead:

`UserImage.objects.filter(photo='a.jpg')`

Edit: Django prepends the upload_path to the file name. The query should then do something similar, for example:

`UserImage.objects.filter(photo='images/users/photos/a.jpg')`

Answer (score 1):

The above answer will correctly work moreover you can use icontains too as i am using

> comment_qs = Upload.objects.filter(title__icontains=str(file_name)).filter(content_type__model='Task')

Answer (score 0):

You need to query with the name of the `photo` in the UserImage model.

```
name = UserImage.objects.all()[0].photo.name
print(name)
```

`media/a.jpg`

```
UserImage.objects.filter(photo=name).all()
```

OR

```
UserImage.objects.filter(photo="media/a.jpg").all()
```

`<QuerySet [<UserImage: UserImage object (1)>]>`